# Stage screenshots error in fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS fuerte, using stageros with willow-erratic.world file, everything works good and the stage simulation pops up. However, on clicking on *View -> Save screenshots* exits the simulation and gives the following error,

```
err: Unable to open stage-000000.png (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/canvas.cc Screenshot)
Segmentation fault
```

Any solutions ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33891/stage-screenshots-error-in-fuerte/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2012-05-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-13**:
Can you try compiling stage from source... I'm curious to see if it's just trying to save files to e.g. /opt/ros where it doesn't have permissions to write and then not failing gracefully.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-05-13**:
@Eric Perko Okay ! things just got worse, I deleted the stage at /opt and tried to build revision 39428 of stage svn - that did not build - number of errors ! Now, I am in a dilemma !

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-13**:
You should have uninstalled simulator-stage, not just deleted it. You could also try reinstalling and then giving yourself permissions (e.g. chmod -R 777 stage_dir), but at this point you may just want to file a ticket for it - no matter the cause, its still a bug if it doesn't work from the .debs

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-05-13**:
@Eric Perko As silly it may sound, I have never filed a ticked - I am getting these bugs in fuerte (another one at - http://answers.ros.org/question/33044/rosversion-in-fuerte) - but somehow filing a ticket doesn't seem a very easy job to me - tried it once, the log in gave some odd error ....

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-05-13**:
@Eric Perko One more thing, in fuerte stage is stage NOT simulator_stage ! which is also an alteration from diamondback and electric !

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-13**:
Right, I forgot Stage became a unary stack. You can file a ticket by finding the correct bug tracker (first place to look is the "report bugs" link on the package docs (e.g. http://ros.org/wiki/stage#Report_a_Bug). You may have to create an account if you don't already have one.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-13**:
For many ROS packages, an account on gforge (https://code.ros.org/gf/) will suffice. Any packages on KForge will require a separate kforge.ros.org account.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-05-13**:
@Eric Perko Okay - doing it ! I guess a gforge account will work with stage ?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-13**:
Yes. Stage package uses the ros-pkg trac, so the code.ros.org account is what you need.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-05-13**:
@Eric Perko https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5442

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-13**:
Go ahead and post that ticket link as the answer, so that people that come to this question later can find it (and then accept it once you are able to... after a week or so I think).

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-05-14**:
@Eric Perko A personal opinion, but I have not found Stage 4.1.1 much to my liking. Stage 3.2.2 was much better, faster, reliable ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ticket raised, https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5442

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2012-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0